# showing success messages in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to show success message if execute is successful. The below code doesn't show the message just deletes it. what am I missing?

```
  $errors = array();
  $delete = $mydb->prepare("update messages set deleted = 'yes' where to_user = ?  and id = ? ");
 $delete->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
 foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
 $delete->execute();
}

  $errors[] = "Message Deleted.";


}


 <div><?php
if ($delete->execute()) { echo $errors;}
?>
   </div>
```

Comment: Check your logic - you're calling `$delete->execute` in the loop, and then at the end, checking it again to see if the delete worked. I expect that latter call is failing, because `$id` is no longer defined.

Comment: Why are you executing the same query over and over again? You never rebind the parameters...

Comment: there is no any problem witth id variable and it is defined. I just didn't include it here

Comment: if `$errors` is an array then you can't just do `echo $errors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$errors seems to be an array so you will have to loop through it to echo errors which can be done by

```
foreach($errors as $value){
  echo $value;
}
```

, but from the above code it seems you have only one value in array so you can use

```
echo  $errors[0];
```

Also note you may need to be change this

```
if ($delete->execute()) { echo $errors;}
```

to

```
<?php
if (count($errors)>0) { echo $errors;}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: `$errors = array();

$delete = $mydb->prepare("update messages set deleted = 'yes' where to_user = ?  and id = ? ");

$delete->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
 $delete->execute();
}
  $errors[] = "Message Deleted.";
}


 <div>
<?php
foreach($errors as $value){
  echo $value;
  echo '<br>';
}
?>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$errors` is An array not a string and you can NOT echo array variable,
you have to use `foreach($errors AS $v) echo $v;`

Comment: And by the way it seems like php error reporting is off so you are not getting the error message from php that arrays can't be printed as strings.

Comment: `$v` is the value of each element inside the array `$errors` as string